# How do you describe columns and rows as variables in functions?

Tags: variables, names

I'm trying to use a table to reference and automatically display inputs for a formula. For example if I type in "steve"(A3) in my input `box1(A1)` it will look up steve on the table and change `box2(B1)` to 12(B3) and display something else(C3) in another box, `box3(C1)`, then I can do things with what shows up in box2 and box3 other places. Currently I'm doing it the hard way and laboriously listing via `"=IFS(A1=A3,B3,A1=A4,B4,A1=A5,B5...)"` and so on for each row. Instead of having to type out each and every row, how do I type something like `"=If(A1=Ax,Bx)"` and Excel understands that x is the same number for both?  While I'm here, how do I tell Excel to do the same things with the Columns? The name for a letter or symbol that represents a number or function is a Variable but looking up variables is apparently something else in this context.

In cell B2:

```
`    `=If(A1=Ax,Bx)
`    `=If(A1=A=row(),B=Row())
`    `=If(A1=A3:A23,B3:B23)
```

Function was supposed to look up row x from name Ax input into cell A1 and display in cell B1 contents of cell Bx, where X is the row number. I'm sure there's some symbol % or something I can input somewhere but I don't know what they're called or how to find them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I wanted with VLOOKUP. Doesn't answer the variable constant question but works.